# How to set node attribute dynamically using NodeBuilder pattern in groovy

Tags: groovy, markup, builder

How do I set a dynamic node attribute based on a condition in groovy when using the NodeBuilder pattern?

Like the following

```
def b = DOMBuilder.newInstance()
b.div ( attribute: "value") {
    if (condition) {
        // Set div.dynamicAttribute to true here
    }

}
```

Preferably it would be nice to reference the current element in the conditional statement since the condition might appear deep down in the structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to evaluate the condition for the dynamic attribute outside the node closure.  For Example:

```
if (condition) {
    b.div(attribute: "value", dynamicAttribute: true) {
        ...
    }
} else {
    b.div(attribute: "value") {
        ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a map of the attributes beforehand:

```
def attributes = [attribute: "value"]
if (condition) {
    attributes['dynamicAttribute'] = true
}
b.div(attributes) {
    ...
}
```